# Separate Time from Date String ios

Tags: ios, swift

How to separate hour and minute from date .

```
let StDate = "2021-04-03T10:15:00Z"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

if let date1 = formatter.date(from: StDate) {
    let tme = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date1)
    print(tme)
}
```

Out Put

15:45

How to get 10:15

Comment: You probably don't want to get 10:15. That time is UTC time. The `Z` present at the end of your date string means that it is UTC (zero seconds from GMT). If you want to display the current timezone the time 15:45 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely happens because you reside in a GMT+5 time zone. Meanwhile, your date string is UTC.

Use this to override the time zone:

```
dateFormatterPrint.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

Comment: you probably meant +05:30

Answer (score 0):

Your `dateFormattedPrint` by default uses your local timezone. Add

```
 dateFormatterPrint.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
```

to make it use GMT.